# Turning a Grayscale Image into a List in Python

Tags: python, list, image, python-imaging-library

It's pretty easy to turn an image into a greyscale version of itself in PIL. But how do I then turn that image into a list of its values, row by row. Not an array. Just a list. In this case the image is 28 x 28.

But assume its 2 x 2 and its greyscale looked like this:

`214, 61`

`131, 121`

then, I would want it to just be a list like this:

`[214, 61, 131, 121]`

Comment: Try converting to NumPy array, and from array to list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Create 2x2 grey image
im = Image.new('L', (2,2), color=128)

print(list(im.getdata()))
```

Output:

```
[128, 128, 128, 128]
```

---

Note that the value returned by `getdata()` is already an iterator, so there's no need to make it into a list if you just want to iterate over it:

```
for px in im.getdata():
   print(px)
```

will work just fine.